# Replacing symbol with vector

Tags: replacement

Consider example:

```
    expr := {-1, 1} * value
    expr /. {value -> {10, 20}}

(* {{-10, -20}, {10, 20}} *)
```

however, I expect to have something like

```
    {-1, 1} * {10, 20}

(* {-10, 20} *)
```

I understand that my problems come from early expansion of `expr`

```
    expr
    (* {-value, value} *)
```

but I don't know, how to deny early expansion of Times operator in `expr`. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: `expr := Hold[{-1, 1}*value]`

Comment: Thanks! My original case was a bit complicated to post here, so I've decided to make it small and easy to understand. It seems I have to post a new question with more context, since I don't see a way to use Hold/ReleaseHold in my setup. BTW is there any way to say, that value is vector of two elements, so that mathematica wouldn't expand it like a vector times scalar?

Comment: In Mathematica you'll always find one more way to do such things. "The better" way depends strongly on your use case. So yes, go on and post a more specific question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two other approaches

With `Indexed`

```
expr1 = {-1, 1}*{Indexed[value, 1], Indexed[value, 2]}

expr1 /. {value -> {10, 20}}
(* {-10, 20} *)
```

With `Inactivate` and `Activate`

```
expr2 = Inactivate[{-1, 1}*value]

expr2 /. {value -> {10, 20}} // Activate
(* {-10, 20} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a "custom multiplication" instead of times:

```
expr := CTimes[{-1, 1}, value]
```

Then you can replace the `value` and evaluate the expression after that by replacing `CTimes` by `Times`.

```
expr /. value -> {10, 20} /. CTimes -> Times
```